# Unable to mount remote directory using SSHFS

Tags: mount, ssh

I installed SSHFS 3.5 via Homebrew on OSX 10.9. I try the following:

```
~$ mkdir link
~$ sshfs user@hostname:/path/to/dir/ ./link
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
the OSXFUSE file system is not available (-1)
the OSXFUSE file system is not available (1)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was just a case of RTFM. I needed to install the kernel extension too, like so:

```
sudo /bin/cp -RfX /usr/local/opt/osxfuse/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs /Library/Filesystems
sudo chmod +s /Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs/Support/load_osxfusefs
```